# How to drop rows with a value of less than a percentage of the maximum per group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with a time series of a signal with some peaks identified:

```py
Time (s) Intensity Peak              
1        1         a
2        10        a
3        30        a
4        100       a
5        40        a
6        20        a
7        2         a
1        20        b
2        100       b
3        300       b
4        80        b
5        20        b
6        2         b
```

I would like to drop the rows where the Intensity value is less than 10% of the maximum Intensity value for each peak in order to obtain:

```py
Time (s) Intensity Peak              

3        30        a
4        200       a
5        40        a
6        25        a
2        100       b
3        300       b
4        80        b
```

How would I do that? I tried looking for a groupby function that would do that but I just cannot seem to find something that fits.
Thank you!

Comment: It is probably easier to think of this as keeping rows you want rather than dropping rows you don't.

Comment: Good question. In case it causes confusion, there are some minor inconsistencies in values between your before and after dataframes which change the results slightly. Minor point, doesn't obscure the meaning of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` to generate a mask:

```
filtered = df[df.groupby('Peak')['Intensity'].apply(lambda x: x > x.max() / 10)]
```

Output:

```
>>> filtered
    Time(s)  Intensity Peak
2         3         30    a
3         4        100    a
4         5         40    a
5         6         20    a
8         2        100    b
9         3        300    b
10        4         80    b
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` to get max from each group and take 10% using [`Series.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html). Now, compare that with `df['Intensity']` and use it for [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).

```
max_vals = df.groupby('Peak')['Intensity'].transform('max').div(10)
mask     = df['Intensity'] > max_vals

df[mask]

#      Time (s)  Intensity Peak
# 2         3         30    a
# 3         4        100    a
# 4         5         40    a
# 5         6         20    a
# 8         2        100    b
# 9         3        300    b
# 10        4         80    b
```